# Error: The Columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, android-room

I am implementing Room Database. Here is my POJO Class

```
public class Task implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "task_name")
    private String task;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String desc;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "finish_by")
    private String finishBy;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "finished")
    private boolean finished;

    @ColumnInfo(name="no_of_days")
    private String no_of_days;

    public String getNo_of_days() {
        return no_of_days;
    }

    public void setNo_of_days(String no_of_days) {
        this.no_of_days = no_of_days;
    }

}
```

This is the DAO Class

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao {

    @Update
    void update(Task task);
    @Query("SELECT task_name,description,no_of_days FROM task")
    List<Task> getTasksandDescription();
}
```

While running my code, I am getting the following error

```
com.example.myapplication1.model.Task has some fields [id, finish_by, finished] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). 
Columns returned by the query: task_name, description, no_of_days. Fields in com.example.myapplication1.model.Task: id, task_name, description, finish_by, finished, no_of_days.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but a warning, it's telling you that you are mapping an SQL to a Pojo but you are not returning all the fields required to set up the Pojo. So your class has more fields than is returned from the query, you can fix this by doing the following.

I. Do a select * to return all the fields

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM task")
```

II. Add @Ignore annotation to the fields you're not interested in

III. Create another Java class that contains only the fields you're interested in and return in from the query instead.